# Kafka installation - classpath is empty

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I try to install kafka on my windows(8), and it's not work.

I download kafka and extract it on c:\kafka after it i change the server.properties and zookeeper.properties.

I set in those file the logs path.

I even try to download an tun zookeper outside the kafka install but the zookeeper runing and the kafka not.

the Error that i get when i try to run this command is:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .config\zookeeper.properties
```

and this is the result:

```
Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running 'gradlew jarAll'
```

Comment: Seems you downloaded the source code jar file. Download the binary jar file and retry.

Comment: Check this out to fix the issue
https://i-am-jabi.medium.com/fixing-classpath-is-empty-69288c1509a2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions is to Download the binary jar file.

go to config\server.properties and config\zookeeper.properties and change the folder. the new folder need to be write with / and not .

and after it you need to got the main folder and run the command:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```

without the . before "config\zookeeper.properties"

Answer (score 1):

I have provided the answer for the similar error [here](https://i-am-jabi.medium.com/fixing-classpath-is-empty-69288c1509a2), check this out.
https://i-am-jabi.medium.com/fixing-classpath-is-empty-69288c1509a2

Here are the steps to resolve the issue:

1. Open kafka-run-class.bat file. You will find this in bin\windows folder of your confluent Kafka.
2. Search for “rem Classpath addition for core” in kafka-run-class.bat file. When you find it, it looks like below.

[image]

Now lets add the below snippet above the “rem Classpath addition for core” line in kafka-run-class.bat file.

```
rem classpath addition for LSB style path
if exist %BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\* (
 call:concat %BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\*
)
```

After adding the above snippet, your file will look like this.

[image]

Now, when you run the bat files under windows folder, they will run fine without any issues. Here is the zookeeper start log after fixing the classpath error.

[image]